# Thread.Sleep only works with breakpoint?

Tags: c#, multithreading, lua

I have a lua script that calls a method named "delay" that calls the following:

```
public void Delay(int millisecondsTimeout)
{
     Thread.Sleep(millisecondsTimeout);
}
```

However, when the lua script calls it, it seems to ignore this line of code and just runs the rest of the code without blocking the thread (the script is ran on a different thread).

However, when I place a breakpoint on the Thread.Sleep line, it works as expected.

Why's that happening? It's so weird!

**EDIT:** This is how I create the script's thread:

```
new Thread(() =>
                {
                    this.Script.DoFile(this.Path);
                }).Start();
```

I use lua.RegisterFunction to register the method, it calls it just fine.

Comment: You just said that the script runs on a different thread. Why do you think `Thread.Sleep()` would have an effect on it then?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel It blocks the current thread, meaning the thread that calls it (the script thread), so why wouldn't it "halt" the script execution?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - different from what is the question. If the script simply calls this then it's a valid question.

Comment: Can you give us the code?

Comment: @MatinLotfaliee I updated the main post.

Comment: what is the breakpoint value of the passed timeout? Are you sure it's 3000 (3 seconds)? or is it maybe going through so fast you don't notice it (ie a hard coded 3000 is very different than a passed value)

Comment: @alykins It is 3000, so the value is fine. I tried putting two breakpoints (one on the Thread.Sleep line and another one on the end of the method). When I pressed continue after calling Thread.Sleep, it did wait 3 seconds before it hit the end of the function breakpoint.

Comment: going to need more info then- can you post the thread creations and maybe the method signatures of the two threads with relevant logic (like where it gets that int that it passes or things like that... maybe checks before it tries to call it if they exist?)

Comment: @alykins I posted it as well.

Comment: I think a good way to help is to create a new fresh project and copy the piece of code that made weird problems... try to make it as simple as possible. I mean, make it 10 or 20 lines. if the problem still exists on that, copy them for us. (but usually the simplifying process, shows the reason of the problem)

Comment: @MatinLotfaliee I'll post a sample code in the main post.

Comment: This is weird. It worked fine with my sample code but i doesn't in the main project.

Comment: start adding the logic in piece by piece then. This is often a good debugging/troubleshooting technique. It is a fast-track way to hone the problem. Eventually, you will add something that will make it break again.

Answer (score 0):

> However, when the lua script calls it, it seems to ignore this line of code and just runs the rest of the code without blocking the thread (the script is ran on a different thread).

If the script is running on a different thread, you should call sleep on that thread. If you call Thread.Sleep, it will sleep the current executing thread. For example:

Thread A -> Starts Thread B
- If you call Thread.Sleep in thread A, will sleep thread A, not thread B.

Since you don't have a loop inside your thread code, it will be impossible to call Thread.Sleep inside the thread B.

One possible solution to this is suspend the background thread from the main thread.

```
myBackgroundThread = new Thread(() => //myBackgroundThread is a private variable.
            {
                this.Script.DoFile(this.Path);
            }).Start();
```

and from the main thread::

```
myBackgroundThread.Suspend();
Thread.Sleep(ms);
myBackgroundThread.Resume()
```